# Implementing MarkDown possibly with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, markdown

I'm trying to make a simple MarkDown-like language for my website.

Here are the conditions:

The strings have no newlines in them.

---

What I would like:

1. A way to make text bold (e.g. **bold** )
2. A way to make text italic (e.g. *italic* )
3. A way to make text underlined (e.g. _underlined_ )
4. Hyperlinks like [text](url)
5. Inline code where MarkDown isn't parsed (e.g. `code` )
6. Combine the above (e.g. [**_underlined and bold link_**)](url) )

If  someone could help me get in the right direction on how to solve this, thanks!

I tried to make regular expressions, but those didn't really work out because you could have a bold tag overlapping a italic tag which made invalid HTML.

Do I have to split the string and work down the string recursively?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a PHP markdown parser using regex a while back to simplify HTML form generation. You are welcome to look through my source (not necessarily saying it's pretty, but it is one way you could do it):

https://github.com/rmcvey/PHP-Markdown-Forms

The regex patterns and matching logic is in [this file](https://github.com/rmcvey/PHP-Markdown-Forms/blob/master/forms_markdown.php)